# Why in the code "456"+1, output is "56"

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "25"+1;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting "5" as output.
when I use "5"+1,output is blank;"456"+1 output is "56".
confused what is going behind the scenes.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you do "25"+1?

Comment: And `"hello" + 1` is `"ello"`, Are you spotting a pattern yet?

Comment: If you add potato to banana, how many frobnitzes do you end up with?

Comment: You should understand C-style strings before you start to do C++ stuff with them.

Comment: Great question to troll PHP/Javascript programmers.

Comment: @florianpeschka Once you understand why my question made as much sense as the asker's code snippet you'll understand what they were doing wrong.

Comment: @Shadur OP isn't doing anything wrong. They are just asking a question.

Answer (score 51):

The string literal `"25"` is really a char array of type `const char[3]` with values `{'2', '5', '\0'}` (the two characters you see and a null-terminator.) In C and C++, arrays can easily decay to pointers to their first element. This is what happens in this expression:

```
"25" + 1
```

where `"25"` decays to `&"25"[0]`, or a pointer to the first character. Adding `1` to that gives you a pointer to `5`.

On top of that, `std::ostream`, of which `std::cout` is an instance, prints a `const char*` (note that `char*` would also work) by assuming it is a null-terminated string. So in this case, it prints only `5`.

Answer (score 14):

Behind the scenes, `"25"` is an array of three characters: two representing `'2'` and `'5'`, and a terminator with the value of zero to mark the end.

An array is a slightly strange creature, with a tendency to change into a pointer (to the first element) if you do anything with it. That's what's happening here: adding one to an array doesn't make sense, so it turns into a pointer. Adding one to that gives a pointer to the second character.

When given a pointer to a character, `<<` assumes it points to a terminated string, and keeps printing characters until it finds a terminator (or explodes in some way, if there isn't one). So giving it a pointer to the second character of a string will print all the characters from the second onwards, as you observed.

If you're new to C and C++, you should first decide which language to learn first, since they're very different. If you choose C++, you'd be wise to become familiar with its friendly, high-level library (such as `std::string` for dealing with strings without this kind of weirdness) before plunging into the low-level madness of arrays and pointers.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: std::string s="25"+1; std::cout<<s; also gives 5 as an output.

Comment: @meet: of course it does. "25"+1 has the same meaning whatever you do with it.

Answer (score 2):

When you write a "", the compiler understands you are putting a string inside. In this case, you are using the function cout, so it prints on screen this string. You are operating with strings when you use the '+' operator, so you are doing a displacement operation before send it to the cout.

Comment: Wrong. A string literal is a `char*` not a `std::string`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch To be fair, it doesn't say `std::string`. Also, a string literal is an array of `const char`, not a pointer.

Comment: Not sure of the `const char` array. I think the standard says `char` for historical reasons.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it doesn't , they are `const char[]`. There used to be an exception that a `const char *` which came from string literal decay could be assigned to a `char *` without requiring a cast.

Comment: displacement operation?

Comment: putting a string inside? displacement? string? This is a really bad, imprecise answer that doesn't use the adequate vocabulary to answer the question properly. It doesn't add any value to the previous answers.