# char concat to string returns wrong length

Tags: c++, string, sockets, byte

simple c++ program that adds a char byte to a string. The resulting length is wrong in the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

   char x = 0x01;

   std::string test;
   test = x+"test";

   std::cout << "length: " << test.length() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "test: " << test << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

the output:

```
length: 3
test: est
```

I am prepending a type byte to the string because I am going to be sending this data through a socket and the other side has a factory that needs to know the type of object to create.

Comment: See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957950/why-in-the-code-4561-output-is-56

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1 + "test" = "est"  // 1 offset from test
```

So you are getting the correct answer.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| t | e | s | t | \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+
  +0  +1  +2  +3  +4
```

What you want is possibly:

```
std::string test;
test += x;
test += "test";
```

Comment: I want to actually add the char to the string, not move the pointer ahead one.?

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating a `char` with a `std::string` as you think you are. This is because `"test"` is actually a literal `const char*`, so you are just doing pointer arithmetic when you add `x` to it. You can replace

```
test = x + "test";
```

with

```
test = std::to_string(x) + "test";
```

Then your [output will be](http://cpp.sh/6zi3)

```
length: 5
test: 1test
```

Comment: `std::to_string()` is new in C++11.  For earlier versions of C++, you can use `std::string(&x, 1)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that will do a different thing