# Can someone please explain this output?

Tags: c++, c++11, output, cout

```
cout<<"ccccc"+2;
```

Output:

```
ccc
```

I tried searching for it online and I know it is a very dumb question but couldn't find anything anywhere. Please if someone could help me out.

Comment: duplicates: [Why in the code "456"+1, output is "56"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28957950/995714), [Why can you add an integer to a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25299156/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why in the code "456"+1, output is "56"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957950/why-in-the-code-4561-output-is-56)

Answer (score 7):

```
"ccccc"+2;
```

`"ccccc"` decays to the `const char *` pointer referencing the first character of the string literal `"ccccc"`. When you add `2` to it, the result references the third element of the string literal.

It is the same as:

```
const char *cptr = "ccccc";

cptr += 2;

cout << cptr;
```

Comment: In C++ `"ccccc"` decays to a `const char *`. `char *cptr = "ccccc";` should give a compile time error.

Comment: there is no need to use a pointer. `"cccc"` is a `char[5]`. I suggest to use `const char c[] = "cccc";`. This would also more closely resemble what is happing in OPs code where the decay to pointer happens due to `+ 2`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The code is only to illustrate what is going on.

Comment: yes and showing `const char c[] = "cccc";  const char* cptr = c+2;` is more closely resembling what is going on, the decay is triggered by `+2` in OPs code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number not exactly as it creates the new array and it does not happen in the original code. cptr represents decayed pointer referencing directly the string literal

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that's not true, `"ccccc"` decays to a pointer even without the `+ 2`. There is no `operator<<(const char (&)[N])` function, only a `operator<<(const char *)` function.

Comment: @mch indeed, but in OPs code is does decay due to `+2`, thats all im trying to say

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote:

```
cout<<"ccccc"+2;
```

The following things happen(to note here):

1. `"ccccc"` is a **string literal**. In particular, it is of type `const char[6]`.
2. Now, this string literal **decays** to a *pointer to `const char`* which is nothing but `const char*` due to **type decay**. Note that the **decayed** `const char*` that we have now is pointing to the **first character** of the string literal.
3. Next, `2` is added to that decayed pointer's value. This means that now, after adding `2`, the `const char*` is pointing to the **third character** of the string literal.
4. The suitable overloaded [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is called using this `const char*`. And since this `const char*` is pointing to the third character of the string literal, you get the output you observe.